# CSS: Percentage width combined with fixed min-width causes divs not to fit in one line

Tags: html, css, responsive

So I've got this issue: I've been working on "responsiveness" of a website consisting of 3 divs (columns - let's call them 'A', 'B' and 'C', all 96% high) + a footer. A and C are of the same class and have 35% width. Column B is 30% wide, but i also set it's min-width to 200px. When i shrink the browser so that column B is 200px wide and can't get any thinner and keep shrinking it, column C jumps down. I'm trying to make them fill with no fixed min-width and a max-width of 35%, while writing max-width: 35%; is not enough to make it happen. 
Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Share your code so we have a demo of what you have now. See how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Sounds like you need to look into CSS @Media queries. You can use these to change the CSS of an element when the screen is below a specified width.

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col colA">A</div>
  <div class="col colB">B</div>
  <div class="col colC">C</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.col{
  height: 96%;
}
.colA, .colC{
  background-color: blue;
  flex-basis: 35%;
}
.colB{
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4nhvtbpe/

Comment: It worked for 3 columns, but now the footer squeezes in between colC and right edge of the screen, on top of the site, even though it has clear:both; set.

Comment: Would need to see your html to help but this works: https://jsfiddle.net/4nhvtbpe/2/

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to keep footer inside the container. Is there any possible way that it could work?

Comment: Yo, i don't know if you noticed on fiddle how the footer gets too narrow at some point when shrinking browser. I suppose it's because it gets scrollable, which makes the hidden part kind of beyond the 100% width. How could i fix this?